# Is there any Pellet molder alternative?

Tags: recycling, plastic

Our groupmates have a research topic that includes making a plastic pellet. We have to think of an alternative way to produce plastic pellets out of melted HDPE plastic bags since we're still students who couldn't afford buying an expensive pellet maker machine. Does anyone know any cheap alternatives for making a plastic pellet?

Comment: Did you do any research? Googling (as one example) [diy plastic pellets](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+plastic+pellets) seems to give enough information.

Comment: You need to show that you have attempted to find an answer.  Rewrite your question addressing why you want to make pellets, what the characteristics of melted HDPE are, what size pellets you need to make, and what the pellets will be used for.  A solution to make pellets the size of hockey pucks is unlikely to be effective for making ones the size of bird shot.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the following two machines:

- The [Precious Plastic Extrusion machine](https://preciousplastic.com/en/videos/build/extrusion.html), an open source, do-it-yourself plastic extruder that is fed with shredded plastic. Use it to create plastic filament in the diameter you need (maybe 3 mm as usual for 3D printers), and collect the filament on a slow-turning spool.
- A machine to cut the filament into small pieces as needed for making pellets. Not sure what would be a good basis for this one, though, but it's a pretty simple machine.

It seems preferable to me to separate the process into the two steps above, as creating the pellets from molten plastic in one step could be more difficult to control in a simple machine. You'd likely deform the soft plastic while cutting the part coming out of the extruder, and the heap of fresh pellets  might also stick together while it is cooling.